# Is it possible to make Chrome App notifications make a sound?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

We've got a Chrome app with working notifications, but no sound is made when the notification pops up. Is there a way to tell Chrome to make a sound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The page that generates a notification can create an `<audio>` element and play it together with the notification. Usually it's done in the background page.

Example from my extension, initialization:

```
var audio_element     = document.createElement("audio");
    audio_element.id  = "notify_sound";
    audio_element.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("audio/notify.ogg");
document.body.appendChild(audio_element);
```

And use:

```
document.getElementById("notify_sound").currentTime = 0; // Rewind
document.getElementById("notify_sound").play();
```

Comment: Beware that notifications can be muted by the user. Thus you won't know whether your sound is annoying a user who needs notifications to be absolutely invisible and silent (e.g., during a presentation, or while recording a podcast). It'd be better to file a feature request for sounds than to assume the user always wants to hear them.